# Cache with JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi I have extended a JpaRepository interface in following way.

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student,Integer>
{
@Query(value= "SELECT s.id FROM student as s where s.createdat >  ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE, :maxage ", nativeQuery = true )
public List<Integer> findWaitingStudentIds(@Param("maxage")int maxAge);
}
```

Here is the `Entity` class.

```
@Entity(name="student ")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer  id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(updatable = false,insertable = false)
    private Date createdat;  
}
```

I want to add cache for  "List findWaitingStudentIds" method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914480/how-to-add-cache-feature-in-spring-data-jpa-crudrepository) maybe this helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can copy paste my answer from this StackOverflow question:

[How should I implement a cache object/system in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818285/how-should-i-implement-a-cache-object-system-in-spring/26825843#26825843)

> Spring introduced abstraction for Cache in 3.x RELEASE. You can read
> about it in official Spring documentation (the site is down today for
> some reason :)), or at this post for example.
>
> http://dzone.com/articles/spring-cache-abstraction-0
>
> With this abstraction, all you need to do to enable cache is to add
> some annotations to your services, like
>
> To add value to the cache
>
> ```
> @Cacheable("customers")
> public Customer findCustomer(long customerId) {...}
> ```
>
> To remove value to the cache
>
> ```
> @CacheEvict(value="customer", allEntries = true)
> public void removeAllCustomers(long customerId) {...}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider reading the [Hibernate Reference Manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache). It helped me quite a lot when I used it for the very first time. It really clarify concepts and the way it works.

Some other answers are present in StackOverflow: [Hibernate Cache Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852685/hibernate-cache-reference).

Several quick tutorials are also available on the Web:

- [Hibernate cache levels tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/hibernate-cache-levels-tutorial.html)
- [Hibernate Caching](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm).
- [Hibernate EHCache Second Level Caching Example Tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2980/hibernate-ehcache-second-level-caching-example-tutorial).
- [...](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hibernate%20cache%20configuration%20example).

I hope al this info helps you.